# Execute a command after choosing the option from a list in BASH

Tags: bash

I need some help.
I am working on a program, it has a list of what you should chose from.
Here is the code

```
PS3="Choose a software to download."
options=("S1" "S2" "S3" "S4" "S5" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "S1" )
            echo "S1"
            ;;
        "S2")
            echo "S2"
            ;;
        "S3")
            echo "S3"
            ;;
        "S4")
            echo "S4"
            ;;
        "S5")
            echo "S5"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            echo "Quit"
            break
            ;;
    *) echo "Invalid Option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

I want the code to execute a command AFTER I choose the Option.
How do I code it?
Thanks!

EDIT:
I know it will echo the text, but I want it to echo it AND execute something more, like a `git clone` command

Comment: What have you tried? This seems so trivial (considering you already wrote the code above), that it's hard for me to even imagine where you see a problem. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: It's already executing a command after you choose an option - `echo`. Just do the same for whatever other command you want to run.

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you want it to do. `select` builds the menu adding a number before each word in your list. When you select the number corresponding to a valid word (e.g. `options=("S1" "S2" "S3" "S4" "S5" "Quit")`) the `case` statement executes the `echo` command for that choice. Just replace `echo` (or add your command below it). If each "command" you speak of is actually many commands, consider writing a function that contains the commands and simply calling the function in your `case` statement under the appropriate case.